# HTML CSS centre align buttons on smaller device screens

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centre align buttons for the mobile screen. The website is a responsive site. Please see code attached.[html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKTOl.png)

Comment: to make center the button  give a fixed width to your div and then use margin-left and margin-right auto.

Comment: Post a [mcve] not images of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: any size px){
    .btn-services{
       display: block;
       width: 20px;
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

and see this to understand: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: Thank you. this helped. and if i want to display two buttons side-by-side on smaller screens how can i achieve that?

Comment: you are welcome,
you can put all the buttons in a div and make the above style to it
i'll explaine
div{
       display: block;
       width: 60px;
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
}
and make the buttons display: inline-block;

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn-container {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  place-items : center;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="btn">I am a Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn">I am another Button</button>
  <button class="btn">and another</button>
  <button class="btn">ok last</button>
</div>
```

Now, you can add this in a media query for mobile screen sizes accordingly.